# Ajax update and remove table rows with node.js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm making ajax table with Node.js. I can update the rows without refreshing whole page, and delete task also. it's not perfect because of below reason, please see the image.

[image]

When I update some row, and I click 'remove' button, it is not working. But after I refresh the whole page, it works well. Maybe this is very verbose question, If you have not enough time - please see js file, there is key of problem... Okay, then the codes are :

**html** : If I load page, the page will find database and show each one. No problem with this I think.

```
<table id="tb-docs">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="50">Active</th>
        <th width="300">Subject</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th width="110">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% posts.forEach( function ( post, index ){ %>
    <tr>

        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td><%= post.Subject %></td>
        <td><%= post.Content %></td>

        <td><button onclick="deleteRow(this,'<%= post._id %>')">Remove</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**js** : I strongly suspect 'append()' in updateRow function. maybe there is something wrong,

```
function updateRow(subject, content){
$.ajax({
    url: "/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'subject': subject, 'content': content },
    success: function(data){

        $('#tb-docs').append('<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="checkbox" checked/></td>' +
        '<td>'+subject+'</td>' +
        '<td>'+content+'</td>' +

        // *** Here Appended button is not worked !!!! ***
        '<td><button onclick="deleteRow('+this+','+data+')">Remove</button></td>' +
                '</tr>');
    }
});
}

function deleteRow(obj, id) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/dbs/destroy/"+id,
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'id': id },
    success: function(data){
        $(obj).closest('tr').fadeOut(300,function(){
            $(obj).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    },
});
}
```

**server (node.js)**

```
// update row handler ===============

app.post('/', function (req, res){
  new posts({
    Subject: req.body.subject,
    Content: req.body.content,
    Active: true
  }).save(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.send(post._id);
  });
});

// delete row handler ===============

app.post('/dbs/destroy/:id',function (req, res){
  posts.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post){
    if (err) res.send(err) ;

    post.remove(function(err, todo, next){
      if(err) return next(err);

      res.sendStatus(200);
    });
  });
});
```

I struggled with it for 2 days. This appending row in table is just trick, right? So I think appended 'button' is not worked, but reloaded page 'button' is worked. Then, How can I do action with appended button?

I think a other way, separate this table html file and ajax get call. but I have a lot of tables, so this is very hard works and not efficient way. Could you tell me what is real problem? Sorry for no fiddle because it is related with database. Anyway Thanks for reading.!

Comment: if you got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ... try to use onclick="deleteRow(this,'+data+')"   instead of onclick="deleteRow('+this+','+data+')"

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef And then... `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list `  . I totally don't know what is problem...

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef  And `"deleteRow(this, "+data+")" ` ---> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` ...

Comment: it should be single quotes for data  "deleteRow(this, '+data+')"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using '+this+' just type this in the onclick function for the deleteRow button.

```
function updateRow(subject, content){
$.ajax({
    url: "/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'subject': subject, 'content': content },
    success: function(data){

        $('#tb-docs').append('<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="checkbox" checked/></td>' +
        '<td>'+subject+'</td>' +
        '<td>'+content+'</td>' +

        // *** Here Appended button is not worked !!!! ***
        '<td><button onclick="deleteRow(this,'+data+')">Remove</button></td>' +
                '</tr>');
    }
});
}

function deleteRow(obj, id) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/dbs/destroy/"+id,
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'id': id },
    success: function(data){
        $(obj).closest('tr').fadeOut(300,function(){
            $(obj).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    },
});
}
```